# Kivy apk crash with FileNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am working on an app using Kivy and Buildozer. At some point, text is loaded from a simple text file. This works perfectly on my PC but this seems to cause the app to crash on my phone when I test the apk. I am using Python3.6 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is the part of the code where the text is loaded:

```
class DataList(object):

    def __init__(self, dict):
        """Construction of the total list depending on booleans"""

        self.total_list = []
        if dict["Characters"] is True:
            char_list = (open("characters.txt", "r").read()).split("\n") # Here is the bug
            #char_list = ["char1", "char2", "char3"]
            self.total_list += char_list
        if dict["Games"] is True:
            #games_list = (open("games.txt", "r").read()).split("\n")
            games_list = ["game1", "game2", "game3"]
            self.total_list += games_list
        if dict["Movies"] is True:
            #movies_list = (open("movies.txt", "r").read()).split("\n")
            movies_list = ["movie1", "movie2", "movie3"]
            self.total_list += movies_list

        while "" in self.total_list: self.total_list.remove("")

    def pick(self):
        """Random picks of x elements in the data list"""
        if self.total_list:
            picks = random.sample(self.total_list, 3)
            return picks
        else:
            return None
```

Here is `adb logcat` result:

```
04-27 15:21:21.395 25975 26011 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
04-27 15:21:21.396 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 116, in <module>
04-27 15:21:21.397 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
04-27 15:21:21.399 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
04-27 15:21:21.400 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
04-27 15:21:21.402 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
04-27 15:21:21.404 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 342, in idle
04-27 15:21:21.406 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 327, in dispatch_input
04-27 15:21:21.407 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/base.py", line 293, in post_dispatch_input
04-27 15:21:21.409 25975 26011 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
04-27 15:21:21.410 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 179, in on_touch_up
04-27 15:21:21.412 25975 26011 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 703, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
04-27 15:21:21.413 25975 26011 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1214, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
04-27 15:21:21.415 25975 26011 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1098, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
04-27 15:21:21.421 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 64, in custom_callback
04-27 15:21:21.422 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/guess.kv", line 37, in <module>
04-27 15:21:21.424 25975 26011 I python  :      on_release: app.generate()
04-27 15:21:21.425 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 63, in generate
04-27 15:21:21.427 25975 26011 I python  :    File "/home/florian/Documents/App/My_apps/guess_android/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 89, in __init__
04-27 15:21:21.429 25975 26011 I python  :  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'characters.txt'
04-27 15:21:21.429 25975 26011 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

Obviously, there is a path issue. What is the solution ?

Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: No way to tell for sure without more information. Are you including your text files in your `buildozer.spec`?

Comment: No, the text file is in the same directory as main.py. Should I include it in my buildozer.spec file ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include those text files in your `buildozer.spec`. You can do it by adding `txt` to the `include_exts` line. Something like this:

```
source.include_exts = py,kv,txt
```